# DataGridView - Editar pelo CurrentRow.Index não sai do Index 1

Tags: c#, datagridview

> Observação: Estou aprendendo usar o DataGrid, então estou testando
> alguns exemplos.

Tenho este formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E este código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProjetoFinal
{
    public partial class frmCadastroClientes : Form
    {
        int i = 0;
        int poc;

        public frmCadastroClientes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i++;
            dgvClientes.Rows.Add(i, txtNome.Text, txtEnd.Text, txtCidade.Text, txtEstado.Text, maskFone.Text, txtEmail.Text);

            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtEstado.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnLimpar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtEnd.Text = "";
            txtCidade.Text = "";
            txtEstado.Text = "";
            maskFone.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Text = "";

            btnGravar.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int poc = dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index;

            txtNome.Text = dgvClientes[1, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEnd.Text = dgvClientes[2, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtCidade.Text = dgvClientes[3, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEstado.Text = dgvClientes[4, poc].Value.ToString();
            maskFone.Text = dgvClientes[5, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dgvClientes[6, poc].Value.ToString();

            btnGravar.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvClientes[1, poc].Value = txtNome.Text;
            dgvClientes[2, poc].Value = txtEnd.Text;
            dgvClientes[3, poc].Value = txtCidade.Text;
            dgvClientes[4, poc].Value = txtEstado.Text;
            dgvClientes[5, poc].Value = maskFone.Text;
            dgvClientes[6, poc].Value = txtEmail.Text;

            MessageBox.Show("Cliente número: " + i + "Alterado!");
        }
    }
}
```

Quanto clico em uma linha os valores dela preenchem os campos do formulário, para que eu possa edita-los, porém sempre que edito outra linha que não seja a 1ª ele não altera e só altera a primeira linha.

**Exemplo:** Tenho o Id: 2, mudei a cidade de: `Salto` para `Itu` porém o que mudou foi o do Id: 1 de `Campinas` para `Itu`.

Espero ter sido claro no que estou pedindo ajuda.

Comment: No lugar de usar `dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index` tenta usar `e.RowIndex` que pega o índice da linha clicada.

Comment: Não tem essa propriedade para usar :d

Comment: Estou usando como base este vídeo: https://goo.gl/MQ7Sd3 aos 22:00min ele faz isso está idêntico.. porém não sei o que preciso pra poder editar a linha que cliquei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, achei onde estava o erro.

**Errado:**

```
private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int poc = dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index;

            txtNome.Text = dgvClientes[1, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEnd.Text = dgvClientes[2, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtCidade.Text = dgvClientes[3, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEstado.Text = dgvClientes[4, poc].Value.ToString();
            maskFone.Text = dgvClientes[5, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dgvClientes[6, poc].Value.ToString();

            btnGravar.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Onde está `int poc` deve ser somente `poc` pois já havia declarado está variável lá em cima.

**Correto:**

```
private void dgvClientes_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            poc = dgvClientes.CurrentRow.Index;

            txtNome.Text = dgvClientes[1, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEnd.Text = dgvClientes[2, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtCidade.Text = dgvClientes[3, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEstado.Text = dgvClientes[4, poc].Value.ToString();
            maskFone.Text = dgvClientes[5, poc].Value.ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dgvClientes[6, poc].Value.ToString();

            btnGravar.Enabled = false;

        }
```